# Change standard name of the bibliography in Memoir class,

Tags: bibliographies, memoir

In the Memoir class, the default name of the bibliography is (drum roll) "Bibliography." I want to change it.

Following advice in the LaTeX Companion, I tried using \renewcommand\bibname{Newname} just to test. The source file typeset correctly but the command did not work: the name remained the same.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: See here for example: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26613: If you are using `biblatex` then `\printbibliography[title=NewName]` shoudl work. Or `\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{NewName}}` if you are using `babel`.

Comment: Thank you. It may not work for me because I'm not using biblatex

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the `memoir` manual the following works.

```
% bibnameprob.tex  SE 631139

\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Short Entries}

\begin{document}

\cite{author-book}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{shortbib}

\end{document}
```

together with

```
%% LaTeX2e file `shortbib.bib'
%% a shortened version of jobname.bib which was
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `tocnocapsprob' on 2018/06/05.
%%
@book{author-book,
title = {Not a Best Seller},
author = {A. N. Author},
location = {The City},
publisher = {T H E Publisher},
year = {2005},
}
```

giving

[image]

You have done something that we can only guess about that causes your problem.

**EDIT FOLLOWING OP'S COMMENT WHICH CHANGED THE QUESTION**

The OP did not supply an MWE so I had to guess at it. It turns out that the OP used the `bibliography` environment which has its own means of changing the title of the bibliography.

```
% bibnameprob2.tex  SE 631139

\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Short Entries} or in article class \refname{...}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{x} book
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful.

Comment: It did not work because I use the bibliography environment. This is what I have: 

\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}



\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{x} book
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

Comment: @Lambert Why did you not provide an MWE; I had to guess at it. I have now provided an edited answer to the question that you should have originally asked.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Your answer works. Here's my MWE